# Matlab: GUI resizes if i use getpixelposition

Tags: matlab, user-interface, position

I made a GUI where i would like to have the position from, in pixels. I set the "Resize behaviour" to "Proportional"
Now i use

```
Position = getpixelposition(Test)
```

Test is the name of the GUI. I added a button to the Gui. Once i click on the button the code runs. But what happens, is that the screen shifts location. It was full size, now it shifts. 38 pixels to the right and 61 down.

Anybody an idea why this is?

Maybe other solutions to get the postition of my GUI?

Comment: A workaround is to programatically set the size of the GUI when that happens, but it would be interesting to see why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behavior on my system (Win32 + MATLAB2012a).

However, to see what causes it:

- type in your Command Window:

  ```
  edit getpixelposition
  ```
- set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function;
- trigger the code tha calls `getpixelposition`;
- step into the function (F11 preferably), and notice when the change of the position takes place; the executed statement would be the cause.

To get the position in pixels, you may use the undocumented `hgconvertunits`. From the .m file:

> `Y = HGCONVERTUNITS(FIG, X, SRCUNITS, DESTUNITS, REF)` converts
>   rectangle `X` in figure `FIG` from units `SRCUNITS` to `DESTUNITS`
>   using the object with handle `REF` as the reference container for
>   normalized units. `REF` can be the root object.

Comment: No can do. Cannot open getpixelposition. It is a p file.

Comment: You should specify the version of MATLAB in your post. Also, do you use the old-style handle graphics, or the new style (proper objects)? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html

Comment: I have R2014a. No idea how i should fine my style handle graphics?
I have a computer with Windows 8 (x64) and Windows 7 (x64). Both have this problem!